# Get current item value from a dropdown menu?

Tags: python

I have a dropdown box. And i want to do this when this item is selected, and that when another item is selected. So i need a way to retreive what is currently selected in the dropdown menu.

The dropdown menu is a EnumProperty. Like the dropdown box to change the rotation mode.

```
bpy.types.Scene.enumprop = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = item_cb)
...

layout.prop(scene, 'enumprop', text='Files')
```

How do i retreive the value of the current selection from a dropdown menu by code?

Comment: Looks good. How your callback looks like? What exactly is wrong with this? From the [API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty): `update is called when this value is modified`

Comment: @poor, The callback was exactly my problem. I had initially no idea how to do it. But i have meanwhile solved it. See answer below :)

Comment: I'd avoid `update`, that's why I posted the API quote.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did in the end then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a update to the prop. Then i can retreive changes from the dropdown box.

```
def myindex(self, context):
    print('changed to,', context.scene.MyEnum)
...

bpy.types.Scene.MyEnum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = item_cb, update = myindex)
```

Another way goes directly across int(context.scene.MyEnum). Then i don't need the update.